# Gauss circle problem and pole of zeta function

Tags: number-theory

I know some approach of the Gauss circle problem and its generalizations by Poisson formula. However, I read that the number of points of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (or integer points $\mathcal{O}$ of a number field $F$) in a ball of radius $X$ is asymptotically dominated by $X^n$... and that this is a consequence of the fact that the Dedekind zeta function of $F$ has a simple pole at 1.

Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

The number of points on $\Bbb{Z}^n$ with magnitude $\le r$ is asymptotic to the volume of the $r$-ball and it is immediate from drawing a cube centered around each lattice point of magnitude  $\le r$ giving a volume comprised between $Vol(B_{r-1/2}(0))$ and $Vol(B_{r+1/2}(0))$. This implies that the zeta function of this lattice has a simple pole at $1$ of residue the volume of the unit ball. The converse follows from a Tauberian theorem similar to the one needed to prove the PNT, where the analytic continuation of $\zeta_{\Bbb{Z}^n}(s)$ follows from the functional equation which follows from the Poisson summation formula.